# AFNetworking 2.5 uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2

I have a really simple question with Swift. I'm trying to figure out why I can't uploading data file using `PUT`. In this example, `self` subclasses `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

```
let request = self.requestSerializer.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("PUT",
            URLString: url, parameters: params as! [NSObject : AnyObject],
            constructingBodyWithBlock: {(formData: AFMultipartFormData!) in
                if attachmentType == "image/jpeg" {
                    formData.appendPartWithFileData(data, name: "image", fileName: attachmentName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            },
            error: nil)

let task:NSURLSessionUploadTask  = self.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil, completionHandler: { (response, responseObject, error) in

        })

task.resume()
```

I can't figure out why it's not uploading, so I was trying to log error, but it's not compiling, any thoughts?

```
    let task:NSURLSessionUploadTask  = self.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil, completionHandler: { (response, responseObject, error) in
        NSLog(error)
    })
```